# Динамические значения bootstrap multiselect

Tags: php, jquery, json

Как можно динамически изменять значения в мультиселекте, при условии, что есть поля в json?
есть экшн, возвращающий json с районами, в зависимости от переданного айди региона:

```
public function actionDistricts($region){
    $query = ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\zo_gcd\District::find()->where(['region_id' => $region])->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name');
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return $query;
}
```

рендер контролов:

```
<?= $this->render('mainsearch/controls/multiselect', [
    'id' => 'region-input',
    'source' => $region,
    'label' => 'Регион',
    'name' => 'multiselect_region[]',
    'class' => 'col-sm-3 col-xs-12 region' ]); ?>
<?= $this->render('mainsearch/controls/multiselect', [
    'source' => $district,
    'label' => 'Район',
    'name' => 'districtslist[]',
    'class' => 'col-sm-3 col-xs-12' ]); ?>
```

Сам контрол:

```
<?php
$zname = preg_replace("~(\\\|\*|\?|\[|\?|\]|\(|\\\$|\))~", "",$name);

if(isset($_GET[$zname])) {
    $values = $_GET[$zname] ?: [];
} else {
    $values = [];
}
?>

<div class="<?= $class ? $class : "col-sm-3 col-xs-12" ?>">
    <label><?= $label ?></label>
    <select name="<?= $name ?>" multiple="multiple">
        <?php foreach ($source as $id => $val) { ?>
            <option <?= in_array($id, $values) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="<?= $id ?>"><?= $val ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

И что-то похожее на событие по изменению селекта:

```
var onchangeBinder = function () {
        // мониторятся только имеющие атрибут name и активные + objecttype
        $('.searchform :input[name][disabled!=disabled], .searchform :input#objecttype').unbind("change").change(function () {
            // определяем ид элемента
            switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
                case "objecttype":
                    setForm();
                    break;
                case "multiselect_region":
                    //something here
                    break;
            }

            console.log("-----------------");
            console.log($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
            console.log("-----------------");

            loadByCatalogCount();
        });
    };
```

Comment: Есть какие-то наработки кода? Вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил всё достаточно костыльной жирной функцией.

```
$multiselect_district = $('.district select');
$multiselect_district.multiselect('disable');
multiselectsettings2 = multiselectsettings;
multiselectsettings2.onChange = function(){
    loadByCatalogCount();
};
$multiselect_district.multiselect('setOptions', multiselectsettings2);
if ($('.district').val() == null) {
    districtRefresh();
} else {

}
function districtRefresh() {

        url_get_districts_by_region_id = 'http://dev.zagorod.spb.ru/districts/';
        $multiselect_region = $('.region select');
        $multiselect_district = $('.district select');
        multipleValues = $multiselect_region.val() || [];

        $multiselect_district.html('');

        for (i = 0; i < multipleValues.length; i++) {
            $.get(url_get_districts_by_region_id + multipleValues[i], function (data) {

                keys = Object.keys(data);

                for (ii = 0; ii < keys.length; ii++) {
                    $multiselect_district.append("<option value=" + keys[ii] + ">" + data[keys[ii]] + "</option>");
                }
                $multiselect_district.multiselect('rebuild');
            });
        }

        if ($multiselect_district.html() == '') {
            $multiselect_district.multiselect('disable');
        } else {
            $multiselect_district.multiselect('enable');
        }
}


$multiselect_region = $('.region select');

multiselectsettings1 = multiselectsettings;
multiselectsettings1.enableFiltering = true;
multiselectsettings1.onChange = function(element, checked) {
    districtRefresh();
};

$multiselect_region.multiselect('destroy');
$multiselect_region.multiselect(multiselectsettings1);
$multiselect_region.multiselect('refresh');
```